# Cambiar BackColor de TextBox en Tiempo de Ejecución

Tags: c#

Tengo varios TextBox asignados en una matriz en mi Formulario, también tengo Botones que representan Colores así que al hacer click en cualquiera de ellos el BackColor debería cambiar.

Fíjate en esta imagen, si yo hago Click en el botón amarillo solo el TextBox que esta en azul debería cambiar....Pero al hacer Click todos los TextBox toman el Color Predeterminado (WhiteSmoke) entonces al recorrer la matriz no puedo identificar cual es el Texbox que tiene un color diferente.

Para cambiarlo, ¿cómo puedo Hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código

```
private System.Drawing.Color amarillo = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFC0");
private System.Drawing.Color azul = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C0FFFF");
private System.Drawing.Color anaranjado = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFE0C0");
private System.Drawing.Color verde = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C0FFC0");
private System.Drawing.Color morado = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFC0FF");
private System.Drawing.Color gris = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5f5");
private System.Drawing.Color verdeStrong = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00C000");
private System.Drawing.Color colorFondoAct;

private void txt00_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    row = Int32.Parse(txt.Name.Substring(3, 1));
    col = Int32.Parse(txt.Name.Substring(4, 1));
    txtSudoku[row, col].BackColor = colorFondoAct;
}

private void botonColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button boton = new Button();
    boton = (Button)sender;
    Color colorFondoAnterior = colorFondoAct;//Obtengo el Color antes de cambiar

    switch (boton.Name) //Establecer Color Activo
    {
        case "yellow":
            colorFondoAct = amarillo;
            break;
        case "green":
            colorFondoAct = verde;
            break;
        case "violet":
            colorFondoAct = morado;
            break;
        case "orange":
            colorFondoAct = anaranjado;
            break;
        case "blue":
            colorFondoAct = azul;
            break;
    }

    for (int fila = 0; fila <= 8; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna <= 8; columna++)
        {
            if (txtSudoku[fila, columna].BackColor == colorFondoAnterior)
            {
                 txtSudoku[fila, columna].BackColor = colorFondoAct;

                 return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button boton = new Button();
boton = (Button)sender;
```

Eso que haces ahí es un absurdo... creas un botón y luego descartas dicho botón para asignarle el sender. Debería quedar así:

```
Button boton = (Button)sender;
```

Por otro lado se supone que el botón presionado ya tiene un color de fondo... ¿Por qué no recuperas dicho color? Es decir, en vez de esto:

```
private System.Drawing.Color amarillo = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFC0");
private System.Drawing.Color azul = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C0FFFF");
private System.Drawing.Color anaranjado = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFE0C0");
private System.Drawing.Color verde = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C0FFC0");
private System.Drawing.Color morado = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFC0FF");
private System.Drawing.Color gris = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5f5");
private System.Drawing.Color verdeStrong = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00C000");

switch (boton.Name) //Establecer Color Activo
{
    case "yellow":
        colorFondoAct = amarillo;
        break;
    case "green":
        colorFondoAct = verde;
        break;
    case "violet":
        colorFondoAct = morado;
        break;
    case "orange":
        colorFondoAct = anaranjado;
        break;
    case "blue":
        colorFondoAct = azul;
        break;
}
```

Poner esto:

```
colorFondoAct = boton.BackColor;
```

Además de quedar más limpio y sencillo te ahorras un error ¿cual?

```
switch (boton.Name)
```

Ahí estás comprobando el nombre del boton... vale ¿cuándo actualizas el nombre de dicho boton? **nunca**, luego el `switch` va a fallar por defecto.

Y para rematar, en tu bucle...

```
for (int fila = 0; fila <= 8; fila++)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna <= 8; columna++)
    {
        if (txtSudoku[fila, columna].BackColor == colorFondoAnterior)
        {
            txtSudoku[fila, columna].BackColor = colorFondoAct;

            return; // <<--- ESTO!!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Ese `return` te sobra. Lo que consigues con eso es que únicamente se sustituya el color del primer botón.

Comment: Ok..Muchas Gracias ... hice tus correcciones pero aun falla...Explicame por favor como quedaria..??

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC ¿Has probado a depurar el código? El depurador de C# es bastante sencillo de usar. Puede ser que tengas errores en otras partes de tu código